# Designing a table which shrinks when browser size is adjusted

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table which I want to make fluid so that when it resizes, the table collapses/shrinks, just like the table on http://sis.bristol.ac.uk/~cckhrb/webdev/code/site/fluid.htm.

How can I design such a table?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give the `<table>` element a `width` of `100%`.

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Was just typing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the example table doesn't have `width: 100%`.

Table resizing is the default in HTML you don't need to "do anything" to design such a table. Most importantly don't set any widths.

IMHO the over-designing and fixation on "pixel perfect design" goes against the basic nature of HTML rendering. Just let it flow.